# Check the table row and column number with database give row id and column id in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, html-table

In my project I have print fixed 10*10 table using two for loops. My database have two fields for `row_id` and `column_id`. I want to check if database given row id and column id is same to the table row number and column number print some string. But in following code check the first database value only.  what is the issue with below code?

```
print('<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">');
 for($x=1; $x<=10; $x++)
    {
     echo "<tr>";
    for($y=1; $y<=10; $y++)
       {
      echo "<td>";


        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        if($row['row_id'] == $x && $row['column_id'] == $y)
        print($row['img_title']);
        else echo"no img";
        }


      echo $x . $y;
      echo "</td>"; 
       }
     echo "</tr>";
    }
print('</table>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   // ....
}
```

Because this code will fetch all the rows once (in your case, your first column and first row) and you cannot reuse it at the other column and row. You can fetch all the rows and store in temporary array.

For example

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $temp[$row['row_id']][$row['column_id']] = true;
}
```

Then in your nested loop:

```
for($x = 1;  $x <= 10; $x++) {
   for($y = 1; $y <= 10; $y++) {
       if (isset($temp[$x][$y])) {
           print("got");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: but how could I pass another array value into the for loops. instead of  `print("got");` i want to print `print($row['img_title']);`

Comment: There are two ways. First one, `$temp[$row['row_id']][$row['column_id']] = $row['img_title'];`. Then value of `$temp[$x][$y]` is the `$row['img_title']`. Second way is to store the whole row. `$temp[$row['row_id']][$row['column_id']] = $row;`. You can access it by `$temp[$x][$y]['img_title']`